# Using Breakpad on libraries: symbol structure query

Tags: c++, stack-trace, google-breakpad

I'm implementing Breakpad into a couple of applications where having a stack trace would be really useful but I slightly confused with what to do with the symbol files for some of our libraries.

I've generated a symbol table for Application and for ourlibrary.so, I've included the exception handler into Applicaion and ourlibrary.so and it generates a nice dump for both, but only picks up the symbol table for Application, so I'm wondering if I have the symbol table for the library in the right place.

Currently its setup like:

- symbols

  - Application

    - Breakpad generated value
    - Application.sym
  - ourlibrary.so

    - Breakpad generated value
    - ourlibrary.so

I'm assuming that I've messed up the symbols directory folder structure but I'm not 100% certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked out what I'd done wrong, the libraries loaded directly pointed all the way back to ourlibrary.so.1.0.0 which is what Breakpad expected the folder to be called, changing the folder name to that resolved it.